# Re-register events with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been adding new elements via jQuery in some of my projects, and I have stumbled across a bit of a cumbersome issue.

Consider the following:

```
$('span.claim').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().html('<span class="unclaim">Unclaim</span>'):
});

$('span.unclaim').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().html('<span class="claim">Claim</span>'):
});
```

And the following markup...

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="claim">Claim</span></li>
    <li><span class="unclaim">Unclaim</span></li>
    <li><span class="claim">Claim</span></li>
    <li><span class="unclaim">Unclaim</span></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, after the initial event is fired, no subsequent events are handled.

I realize I could completely restructure and use the `.bind()` function, but because of the complexity of my project this isn't really all that feasible.

How would I go about re-binding the events after the new elements are created without ditching my anonymous functions, or is it even possible?

Comment: Any reason for creating new HTML elements instead of changing text and class names on click?

Comment: There's a lot more going on than just creating the elements. This was just intended to be a simple example of what's happening, not a literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to look at jQuery live events:
[http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

**Update:**

As mentioned on the above page:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: +1 - I did not know about the live, that is very, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
$('a.claim').click(function() {
    $(this).html('Unclaim').addClass('unclaim').removeClass('claim');
});

$('a.unclaim').click(function() {
    $(this).html('Claim').addClass('claim').removeClass('unclaim');
});
```

Option 2:

```
function bindClaim(){
$('a.claim').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().html('<span class="unclaim">Unclaim</span>');
    bindUnclaim();
});
}

function bindUnclaim(){
$('a.unclaim').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().html('<span class="claim">Claim</span>');
    bindClaim();
});
}

bindClaim();
bindUnclaim();
```

Option 3 (recommended):

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live instead of bind.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `.live()` or re-binding this one. You only need one method:

```
$('.claim,.unclaim').click(function() {
    var claimed = $(this).hasClass('claim') ? 'Unclaim' : 'Claim';
    $(this).text(claimed).attr('class', claimed.toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: That's not really a viable solution because of the complexity of the actual events. The example given was only intended to be a simple example; much more is actually happening in each event.

Comment: It's still a good idea to keep the event simple and apply methods depending on the target (event delegation)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
clickBtn.on("click.claim", evt => {
    clickBtn.off("click.claim");
    });
```